# How to display dropdown menu items inside the dropdown using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Below is my html:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
         <ul  class="list-unstyled" id="slider">
         </ul>
    </div>                        
 </div>
```

Below is my javascript:

```
var locationbegin="<div class='form-group'><label>Location</label><select  
class='form-control' id='location'><option>test</option>";
$("#slider").append(locationbegin); 

var locationoptions = "<option>tester</option>";
$("#slider").append(locationoptions);

var locationend="</select> </div>";
$("#slider").append(locationend);
```

Below is the output:

[image: output]

The problem is the tester comes out of the location dropdown. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong. You can also use http://rendera.herokuapp.com/ to render the code.

Edit: The reason the javascript is separated is because of some other javascript code in between in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going wrong in not using proper HTML. You have to close the tags or the browser does this for you whenever it computes it should. `append` first turns your HTML into  NodeList (which results in the `select` and `div` being closed) and afterwards i is appended to the slider. Now, if you append further `options` onto that HTML structure, you are ffectivly appending thos behind the closed `div`.

You should keep a reference to the `select` to be able to add more optinos whenever you like:

a) create the surrounding markup:

```
var myFormField = $('<div class="form-group"><label>Location</label><select class="form-control" id="location"><option>test</option></select></div>')
```

b) find the `select` and store it to a variable:

```
var mySelect = myFormField.find('#location');
```

c) add as many options as you like

```
mySelect.append('<option>Value 2</option>');
mySelect.append('<option>Value 3</option>');
mySelect.append('<option>Value 4</option>');
```

Comment: I understand that.  I reviewed my html and noticed the closing tags were automatically added. However i need them separate due to a loop for the middle java script as it uses data from the database. Is there a way to apend without automatically adding the closing tags ?

Comment: @ShuyaibAbdullah No there is no way of disabling closing tags in HTML. You got a wrong concept of working with HTML. Please use the the proper DOM methods to acces and manipulate elements. One very simplistic example is given above.

Answer (score 0):

Oh this is not how it works. `.append` will automatically add `closing tags` if your HTML strings doesnt have it.

So just after the first append call, your html will become:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <label>Location</label>
    <select class='form-control' id='location'>
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And further insertions will happen after this HTML.

**So instead, do this:**

```
var locationbegin="<div class='form-group'><label>Location</label><select  
class='form-control' id='location'><option>test</option>";
var locationoptions = "<option>tester</option>";
var locationend="</select> </div>";

$("#slider").append(locationbegin + locationoptions + locationend);
```

Comment: Thanks. I reviewed my html and noticed the closing tags were automatically added. However i need them separate due to a loop for the middle java script as it uses data from the database. Is there a way to apend without automatically adding the closing tags ?